# Insert block inside static block magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, static-block, cms-block, home-page

I create static block with reference name 'seller_registration_form'  from Magento 2 backend which loaded in home page like this:

[image]

Now i want to insert additional content from my module, so i created cms_index_index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <referenceBlock name="seller_registration_form">
     <block class="Test\Customlayout\Block\Sellerform" name="sellerform" template="Test_Customlayout::sellerform.phtml"/>
  </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

but the phtml file never loaded in home page, i already make sure the block file in correct place and the phtml inside view/frontend/templates folder

Comment: Is there any reasons that you didn't insert blocks directly under content?

Comment: @PYYick the main reason, if i want to disable the module, then automatically the block wont be loaded again

Comment: How about if you use `<body>` to embed `<referenceBlock>`?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't place your `<referenceBlock>` inside `<body></body>`. In [Layout file types](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html#layout-types-page) from official document:

> Page layout declares the wireframe of a page inside the  section

Also in same official document:

> `<body></body>` is the parent of `<referenceBlock>`

So in your `cms_index_index.xml`, you should embed `<referenceBlock>` with `<body>`. So that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="seller_registration_form">
            <block class="Test\Customlayout\Block\Sellerform" name="sellerform" template="Test_Customlayout::sellerform.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: We need to put inside `<body></body>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with you XML code

correct like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="Test\Customlayout\Block\Sellerform" name="sellerform" template="Test_Customlayout::sellerform.phtml"/>
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```